# How to restrict HDFS folder access one at a time for a user?

Tags: security, hdfs

Its kind of weird use case.

For example,  `user A` has access to two different folders in HDFS, how to restrict the `user A` can access one folder at a time?

Accessing folder's can be via direct putty login or hive table or any other form of accessing those folders [Spark, BI tools etc...]